# Laravel Route variable limited to 17 characters

Tags: php, regex, laravel, routes

In Laravel, I am trying to accomplish the ability to have a variable quantity of categories in a URL, followed by the slug. For example:

www.trashaccount.com/category1/category2/slug

I am using a route pattern in Laravel to identify the categories

```
Route::pattern('cat', '([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*');
```

and the demo/test route looks like this:

```
Route::get('test/{cat}/{slug}', function($cat, $slug) {
    $categories = explode('/', $cat);
    $i = 1;
    foreach($categories as $category)  {
        echo "category " . $i . ": " . $category . "<br>";
        $i++;
    }
    echo "slug: " . $slug . "<br>";
});
```

This can be tested at www.trashaccount.com/test/{cat}/.../{slug}

This code successfully pulls out a variable number of categories, of any character length; for example this works:

http://www.trashaccount.com/test/cat1/cat2/cat3/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdevg/my-slug

Where it breaks, is in the number of characters of the final element, the {slug}. For some reason anything beyond 17 characters throws a NotFoundHttpException. So, this does not work:

http://www.trashaccount.com/test/cat1/abcdefghijklmnopqr

But if you simply delete the "r" (the 18h character), it works.

To clarify (as my post was being misinterpreted on another forum), you can type as many categories as you want, they can be any length (respecting HTTP limits), and they will be accepted and processed. The final element that I have labeled as {slug}, can not be longer than 17 characters without throwing a NotFoundHttpException error.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I find this behavior quite weird to be honest.

I had nothing to do so I started looking into Laravel's internal code to see what is wrong and I came to the conclusion that if the *last part of the route* is longer than *17 characters* then it fails.

Everything happens in *[Illuminate\Routing\Matching\UriValidator->matches() line 25](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/Matching/UriValidator.php#L19)*.

Here's some debug prints using `/test/first-category/testingslug`:

```php
preg_match("#^/assets/(?P(?!\.\.)(.*))$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslug");

// successful
preg_match("#^/test/(?P([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*)/(?P[^/]++)$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslug");

category 1: first-category
slug: testingslug
```

Everything is alright until I try to use a slug longer than 17 characters.

I try with `/test/first-category/testingslugmuchlonger`:

```php
preg_match("#^/assets/(?P(?!\.\.)(.*))$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslugmuchlonger");   

// fails
preg_match("#^/test/(?P([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*)/(?P[^/]++)$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslugmuchlonger");

preg_match("#^/assets/(?P(?!\.\.)(.*))$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslugmuchlonger");  

// fails again
preg_match("#^/test/(?P([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*)/(?P[^/]++)$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslugmuchlonger");
```

It's repeated because the framework checks if there are alternative routes with.. same routing but different methods in *[Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php->match() line 141](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php#L141)*.

Now I tried to debug those two `preg_matc()` in separated file:

```php
$works = null;
preg_match("#^/test/(([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*)/([^/]++)$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslug", $works);
var_dump($works);

$fails = null;
preg_match("#^/test/(([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*)/([^/]++)$#s", "/test/first-category/testingslugmuchlonger", $fails);
var_dump($fails);
```

And this is what they return:

```php
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(32) "/test/first-category/testingslug"
  [1]=>
  string(14) "first-category"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "first-category"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "testingslug"
}

array(0) {
}
```

There must be something wrong (?) with preg_match in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

add this line to boot function on RouteServiceProvider.php

```
Route::pattern(':route_variable', '[a-zA-Z-]{0,255}+');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @GiamPy for looking into this and the effort you put forth in your Answer, it is very appreciated.

I beat my head against the wall for a few more hours and started playing with the regex pattern. I couldn't get the idea out of my head that I was matching the final forwardslash of the categories, but also defining that forwardslash as the separator between {cat} and {slug} in the Route. This suspicion directed me towards [positive lookaheads](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to remove the final forwardslash and slug from the result.

To be completely honest, I am not sure if this was the problem or not as I eventually resorted to easter egging regular expressions until I found something that works:

```
Route::pattern('cat2', '.+(?=\/.+)');
```

This pattern matches any character (.) one or more times (*), followed by (?=) a forwardslash (/), any character (.) one or more times (*) without including it in the search (functionality of a positive lookahead ?=).

This can be verified at www.trashaccount.com/test2/cat1/cat2/veryverylongslugthatshouldbreak.

If anybody would like to correct me, or expand on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern instead:

```
Route::pattern('cat', '[-a-zA-Z0-9]+(\/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)*');
```

The pattern matches expressions the same way as `([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*` except you will be sure that {cat} will be never ended by a forward slash. **I think** the `/` between `{cat}` and `{slug}` is matched in `cat` pattern **when** -- and I don't know why -- `{slug}` is longer than 17 characters. As @GiamPy said, it's probably a *bug* in `preg_match` function.